# array_append function is not working

Tags: postgresql

I need to append an item to existed array in postgresql.
I wrote this code (plpgsql function):

```
perform array_append (arrayA::integer[],id);
```

Since it didn't work I tried:

```
raise notice '%', arrayA;
perform array_append (arrayA::integer[],id);
raise notice '%', arrayA;
```

It gives:

```
NOTICE:  <NULL>
NOTICE:  <NULL>
```

Why the array isn't updated?

Comment: `v_arraya := arraya || id` or `v_array := array_append(arraya, id);` (that assumes that the variable `arrraya` **is** indeed an array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PERFORM` query discard the results. `array_append` doesn't update the array you specify in the first parameter. It only reads the its values.

You should change your code to:

```
select array_append (arrayA::integer[],id) into v_arrayA;
```

Comment: The select is not necessary, you can just assign the result to the variable.