# concat to array while looping in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have an array of strings and I need to loop through the array; while looping for each string, I need to loop up the ID of that string in a table and create an INT array of those IDs.

Effectively, I need to go
FROM:

```
{"a", "b", "c"}
```

TO:

```
{3,6,8}
```

I am getting this loop going with no errors, and I get the correct ID for each string in the original array, but I have an empty array declared which does not seem to get populated...
This is the code

First raise notive gives me the correct privilege_group_id, but the second raise notice still returns an empty array.. so no concat happens. I tried ARRAY_APPEND() with the same results, always an empty array.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why a loop at all? Looks like you could simplify the complete thing to `select array_agg(privilege_group_id FROM privilege_group WHERE privilege_group_code = any(a_existing_user_group_codes)`

Comment: because I'm really bad at SQL :-) . You're right, your statement is much simpler

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
[array_append function is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34337175/array-append-function-is-not-working)

You have to use SELECT instead of PERFORM and then INTO the same array

```
SELECT  ARRAY_APPEND(a_groups_to_int_array, v_single_exisisting_user_code) INTO a_groups_to_int_array;
```